# Possible to change netStream end time?

Tags: actionscript-3

is it possible to change the netStream end time?
For example I know you can change the start time by using

```
netStream.play(movieName,20)
```

The number 20 being the number of seconds to skip and start the video from, I was just wondering if there was something I could call to automatically make the video call or be given the status

> NetStream.Play.Stop

when it reaches a time point in seconds.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, you'll have to track that yourself and run ns.pause() yourself.  You may want to use [onMetaData](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/net/NetStream.html#event%3aonMetaData), which will give you the meta data you may find key (such as for looping a video when it reaches the end duration).

Here's a sample solution:

```
var stopTimer:Timer = new Timer(20*1000, 1);
stopTimer.addEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER, stopVideo);

function startVideo(path:String):void {
    ns.play(path);
    ns.seek(0);
    stopTimer.start()
}

function stopTimer(e:Event):void {
    ns.stop()
}
```